# Equal sizeofs of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, tree, sizeof

I wrote for training purposes my own (simple) implementation of a tree class in C++. At some point i asked myself how much memory this class uses. So i tried:

```
cout << sizeof( tree<int> ) << " " << sizeof( tree<float> ) << " " << sizeof( tree<double> );
```

And the output is:

```
24 24 24
```

Why is there always the same size, even if I specify a different type?

Here's my class:

```
template <typename T>
class tree
{
private:
   T val;
   tree< T > *left;
   tree< T > *right;

public:
    tree();
    tree( T val );
    ~tree();
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're compiling on a 64 bit system, where pointers are 8 bytes long. They also need to be 8 byte aligned, to avoid performance penalties, so the compiler is inserting padding between `val` and `left` in order to ensure that alignment.